# Does calling register multiple times on the same subscriber results in multiple events calls?

Tags: android, otto

I need Otto to register on `onCreate()` and also on `onResume()`

1. Does it result in the same subscriber registered multiple times ?
2. Do I consequently have to call unregister twice ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Does it result in the same subscriber registered multiple times ?

Not. It will fail at registration because same subscriber must never be registered more than one time.

> Do I consequently have to call unregister twice ?

Same rule is applied here. Unregister must happen only once. Second call to either `register()` or `unregister()` will throw IllegalArgumentException. This behavior helps you to find out issues in your code earlier.

> I need Otto to register on onCreate() and also on onResume()

You should either reconsider you decision to register twice or choose another library (e.g. [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus)) because Otto won't allow you to do so. Best practice is to register in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am planning on creating a service that will register with an otto bus, so I was wondering if I should register in the onCreate() or the onStartCommand(), which could be called multiple times.  If I put it in the onStartCommand() method it **would** register multiple times.

Searching around I found your question and also this post on google+ by Jake Wharton OTTO's creator/owner.  From this is sounds like it is considered a application bug to call register on an object more than once.

Here is the comment I found On google +

> If you call register on an object that's already registered it will crash. That's a bug in your app!

and here is the link.

https://plus.google.com/communities/109244258569782858265/stream/67e6b6dd-0dcd-40c8-9823-47319d798c25

So I don't think you can call it in your onCreate() and onResume() methods.